# Traducción de curl de PHP a C#

Tags: php, c#, webservice, rest, curl

Por un proyecto personal, estoy intentando implementar la [api de Keep2Share](https://github.com/keep2share/api).

La api tiene una documentación muy pobre, pero muestra una implementación de la misma en php, el asunto, es que cuando llegue a lo relacionado con subir un archivo, me estoy topando con que mis intentos siempre reciben el siguiente response.

> {"name":"Bad Request","message":"Wrong signature. IP
>   1**.58.*54.213","code":0,"status":400}

La implementación en php que muestran como ejemplo en github es la siguiente:

```
$data = $this->getUploadFormData($parent_id, $preferred_node);
$curl = curl_init();
        $postFields = $data['form_data'];

        $postFields[$data['file_field']] = new CURLFile($file);

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $data['form_action'],
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields,
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($this->verbose) {
            echo '<<', $response, PHP_EOL;
        }
        return json_decode($response, true);
```

Donde `getUploadFormData` es una llamada al webService, que retorna un json con al siguiente estructura:

```
status: [success]
status_code: [200,400]
form_action: string
file_field: string
form_data: [
    params: string
    signature: string
]
```

Ahora, pasando a mi caso particular, estoy intentando implementarlo con la clase `HttpClient` de la siguiente manera

```
var dat = await GetUploadFormData();

            HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(dat.form_data.signature);
            HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())

            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(stringContent, "signature", "signature");
                //formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file_field", "file1");
                formData.Add(bytesContent, "file", "file");
                var response = await client.PostAsync(dat.form_action, formData);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                }

            }
```

Cabe aclarar, que `GetUploadFormData();` devuelve la información del json que mencione arriba sólo que la función la deserializa en un objeto.

Asumo, por lo que devuelve el response, que `signature` no esta llegando donde debe llegar.

¿Cómo debo enviarla para que llegue de la misma manera que en la implementación de php?

Gracias!

EDIT

Agrego un ejemplo del json que se obtiene en php como `$data` y en C# como `dat`

```
   "status":"success",
   "code":200,
   "form_action":"http://file-api-27.keep2share.cc:8000/upload",
   "file_field":"file",
   "form_data":{  
      "ajax":true,
      "_params":null,
      "signature":"2eda59a25137a78ef05513c60182cebe9972d9d1b80d9e643e0a8104dcdf42f59cfbc76680c7caf2d93e090c74ebdcf19da664c53e9da14992d604469a634887"
    }
```

Comment: pero en el codigo de php no veo donde asignan el signature, en el codigo c# lo asignas como parte del content pero en php ni siquiera aparece en el json que obtienes de getUploadFormData()

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por responder, `signature` esta dentro del array `$data['form_data']`, te das cuenta?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ahora edito la pregunta y dejo un ejemplo del objeto `$data` (que es tal cual yo lo recibo en c# solo que yo lo mapeo a un objeto, en el código es el objeto `dat`)

Comment: bien, pero entonces lo que espera no es un content con el nombre signature sino que es un json en donde se indique ajax:true, _params":null, y "signature":"2e...", ese es el contenido que debes enviar, es un json, no un simple string

Comment: recomendaria que intentes invocar el servicio usando PostMan https://www.getpostman.com/  asi podras armar el body con ese json he invocarlo con post, sera mas facil de ver como depsues pasar eso a c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando un poco con Postman, también haciendo `var_dump` en php logré ver que no estaba enviando un parámetro, el parámetro `params`, utilicé el Pegado Especial en Visual Studio para que me crease la clase mediante un json de response, el problema allí fue que, justamente, se llamaba `params` entonces lo pegó como `_params` y obtenía siempre un valor `null` al momento de serializar el objeto.

La solución estuvo en corregir ese problema usando `Newtonsoft.Json` y `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "params")]` para la conversión.

Por otro lado, estaba usando mal el tercer parámetro de MultipartFormDataContent.Add() que representaba el nombre del archivo y al ser un parámetro de texto plano estaba produciendo un conflicto.

En fin,

```
//Defino los parámetros que voy a pasar en la query            
            HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(dat.form_data.signature);
            HttpContent ajaxContent = new StringContent(dat.form_data.ajax.ToString());
            HttpContent paramsContent = new StringContent(dat.form_data._params);
            HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Defino un timeout alto
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
                using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    formData.Add(stringContent, "signature");
                    formData.Add(paramsContent, "params");
                    formData.Add(ajaxContent, "ajax");
                    formData.Add(bytesContent, "file", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".mp4");

                    try { 

                        var response = await client.PostAsync(dat.form_action, formData);

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                            {
                                var modelo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadedModel>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                                return modelo.link;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error en el método MyUploadFileMethod(string fileName)\n"+ex.Message+"\n"+ex.InnerException?.Message?? "");
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            }
```